# session stroage to save dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these two scripts. The first saves the storage of the model then after the page refreshes loads that model into the dropdown and opens the text file containing the corresponding year values into the second dropdown.

The second should do the same which everything is working great. The storage is saving but the dropdown is not populating? Is the reason it is not displaying in the dropdown because the options are not located in the html?

Also is there a more efficient way to combine these two. I have a set of 6 dropdowns all dependent on the other that I would like to do the same.

```
 <script>
$(function() {
    $('#vehic_sel_model').change(function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('model', this.value);

    });

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('model')){
        $('#vehic_sel_model').val(sessionStorage.getItem('model'));
        $("#vehic_sel_year").load("/v/vehicle-selection/cache/" + sessionStorage.getItem('model') + ".txt");
    }
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#vehic_sel_year').change(function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('year', this.value);

    });

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('year')){
        $('#vehic_sel_year').val(sessionStorage.getItem('year'));
        $("#vehic_sel_trim").load("/v/vehicle-selection/cache/" + sessionStorage.getItem('year') + ".txt");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a JsFiddle of this that replicates the issue?

Comment: I cannot because the second option values are not in the html. They are populated from a text file after the first has been selected

Comment: JsFiddle provides methods for imitating Ajax calls: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html.  You could also allow jsfiddle.com origin on your server. If these methods are unusable, It would at least be helpful to see the text files that are being fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this when pulling from text files. I had to bind the sessionsotrage.GetItem to the .load:

```
$(function() {
        $('#vehic_sel_model').change(function() {
            sessionStorage.setItem('model', this.value);

        });

       $('#vehic_sel_year').change(function() {
            sessionStorage.setItem('year', this.value);

       if(sessionStorage.getItem('model')){
            $('#vehic_sel_model').val(sessionStorage.getItem('model'));
            $("#vehic_sel_year").load("/v/vehicle-selection/cache/" + sessionStorage.getItem('model') + ".txt", function(){
              $('#vehic_sel_year').val(sessionStorage.getItem('year'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('year')){ // <-- Problem here. You've forgotten if statement bracket.
    $('#vehic_sel_year').val(sessionStorage.getItem('year'));
    $("#vehic_sel_trim").load("/v/vehicle-selection/cache/" + sessionStorage.getItem('year') + ".txt");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out in my code here... But that is actually what is on my site. Im still having the same issue